# Import Excel data to SQL Server table using VB.Net application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, excel-2016

I found several articles on this topic but the issues are different. I'm trying to import data from an Excel 2016 file into SQL Server 2017 using a VB.net application, so that the end-users need not to have SQL Server installed on their machines. I ran the application in debug mode to identify the issue.

Again I read articles on various instances related to the following error:

> The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

My code:

```
Dim TheData As DataTable = GetExcelData(OpenFileDialog1)

Private Function GetExcelData(File As OpenFileDialog) As DataTable
    Dim oleDbConnection As New OleDbConnection

    Try
        OpenOLEDBConnections(oleDbConnection, "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0;Data Source=" & File.InitialDirectory & _
        File.FileName & "; ;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;""")

        Dim oleDbDataAdapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select '' as ID, 'AL' as Supplier, LTRIM(RTRIM(GRADE)) AS GRADE, [ship date] as shipdate, LTRIM(RTRIM(coil)) AS coil, L15*1000 AS L15, H15*1000 AS H15 FROM [sheet1$] where COIL is not null group by GRADE, [SHIP DATE], COIL, L15, H15", oleDbConnection)
        Dim dataTable As DataTable = New DataTable()
        oleDbDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable)
        oleDbConnection.Close()

        Return dataTable
    Catch ex As Exception
        oleDbConnection.Close()

        Return Nothing
    End Try

End Function

Private Sub OpenOLEDBConnections(ByRef cnData As OleDbConnection, cnDataConstr As String)

    If Not cnData.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cnData.Close()
    If cnData.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        cnData.ConnectionString = cnDataConstr
        cnData.Open()
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193798/discussion-on-question-by-landon-import-excel-data-to-sql-server-table-using-vb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I spent a day and half, I somehow managed to resolve the issue by going through the following link and tried the option mentioned by *Manju K Gowda Monday, May 14, 2012 12:14 PM*
[Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-quotthe-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local?forum=vstsdb) and also modified my connection string provider from OLEDB 15.0 to 12.0.

To be precise, while building the solution either in Debug or release mode, keep the Configuration Manager to x86 instead of AnyCPU

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is the silver bullet, but i dont like the look of your connection string. There appears to be a ";" out of place. Try this one

```
Dim XLSFile As String = "C:\DATA\test.xlsx"
Dim connstring As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" &
    "Data Source=" & XLSFile & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Try installing ACE provider from the following link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=13255

How to import Excel into SQL Server, check out on

https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/c-programming/office-development-in-visual-studio/

Or try using this snippet

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel


Public Module Program
    Public Sub Main()
        Dim officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application")

        If officeType Is Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, Excel must be installed!")
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit")
            Console.ReadLine()
            Return
        End If

        Const fileToRead As String = "C:\TMP\FirstTest.xlsx"
        Dim xlApp As Excel.Application = Nothing
        Dim workbooks As Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
        Dim xlWorkBook As Excel.Workbook = Nothing
        Dim sheets As Excel.Sheets = Nothing
        Dim t1 As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

        Try
            xlApp = New Excel.Application()
            Console.WriteLine($"Trying to open file {fileToRead}")
            workbooks = xlApp.Workbooks
            xlWorkBook = workbooks.Open(fileToRead, 0, True, 5, "", "", True, Origin:=Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, Delimiter:=vbTab, Editable:=False, Notify:=False, Converter:=0, AddToMru:=True, Local:=1, CorruptLoad:=0)
            sheets = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
            Dim dic = New List(Of String)()

            For Each mSheet In sheets

                dic.Add($"[{t1.Name}$]")
            Next

            Using myConnection = New OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={fileToRead};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR = YES;'")

                Using dtSet = New DataSet()

                    For Each s In dic
                        Console.WriteLine($" Processing {s} table")
                        Dim myCommand = New OleDbDataAdapter($"select * from {s};", myConnection)
                        myCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", s)
                        myCommand.Fill(dtSet)
                    Next

                    For Each t As DataTable In dtSet.Tables
                        Console.WriteLine($" Table {t.TableName} has {t.Rows.Count} records")
                    Next
                End Using
            End Using

            dic = Nothing
            Console.WriteLine("Successfully imported!")
            Console.WriteLine("After closing Console Windows start Task Manager and be sure that Excel instance is not there!")
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit")
            Console.ReadLine()
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine($"Error importing from Excel : {e.Message}")
            Console.ReadLine()
        Finally
            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

            If sheets IsNot Nothing Then
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(sheets)
                sheets = Nothing
            End If

            xlWorkBook.Close()

            If xlWorkBook IsNot Nothing Then
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook)
                xlWorkBook = Nothing
            End If

            xlApp.Quit()

            If xlApp IsNot Nothing Then
                Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(xlApp)
                xlApp = Nothing
            End If

            GC.Collect()
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        End Try
    End Sub


End Module
```

Comment: I Installed the ACE and I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Change the connection string like this $@"Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={fileToRead};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR = YES;'"))
                {

Comment: OpenOLEDBConnections(oleDbConnection, $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.15.0; Data Source= & File.InitialDirectory & _
                    File.FileName & "; Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;'")

Comment: Replace ACE.OLEDB.15.0 with ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Comment: It still showing errors in the new formatting. Can you please help me to correct it

Comment: Did you explore my example on Red Gate? There is a solution on GitHub as well.

Comment: I didnt and I'm trying your statements here.

Comment: What kind of error do you receive now? It is not the same as before.

Comment: My code was completely in VB.net and $ doesnt recognized as a valid character

Comment: This is new feature in VS2017 and works with VB.NET as well. You can use String.Format instead. Check out my updated answer. There is complete VB.NET code inside.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that